# Gravity Forms - jQuery code only works on Desktop and Tablet but not Mobile

Tags: jquery, wordpress, mobile, gravity-forms-plugin

I found the below code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71916291/gravity-forms-how-to-hide-some-options-in-a-dropdown-pricing-field-based-on-va/71958461#71958461) question.

The code works great in Chrome, Firefox and Safari on desktop and tablet but does not work on mobile. I'm trying on an iPhone with Chrome and Safari but no dice. Any ideas why it wouldn't work?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
     $("#input_54_11").change(function() {
          var property_state = jQuery(this).val();
          if (property_state == 'Georgia') { // get the selected state
            jQuery("#input_54_68 option[value='Condominium']").hide();//replace with your value
          }else{
            jQuery("#input_54_68").children().show()
          };
     });
});
```

Comment: do you know what part of it isn't working? you can use something like https://www.browserstack.com/  and add console.log to work out where the issue is. The only part that looks like it needs fixing is ```property_state == 'Georgia' ``` change to ```property_state === 'Georgia' ```

Comment: I connected my iPhone to my iMac and used the Safari web inspector to check the code and I see my script in the header wrapped in script tags but the jQuery code itself is showing up as a text node. Not sure why this would happen on mobile browsers.

Answer (score 0):

it sounds like jquery not loading you can add a test for that and add a fallback like so:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>')</script>
```

you need to swap the

```
js/jquery-3.6.0.min.js
```

to be the minified version of jquery that you have in the shipped solution source files, if your using require then

```
requirejs.config({
  enforceDefine: true,
  paths: {
    jquery: [
      'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js',
      //If the CDN location fails, load from this location
      'js/jquery-3.6.0.min.js'
    ]
  }
});

//Later
require(['jquery'], function ($) {});
```

also, try adding CDATA tags

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<![CDATA[
// content of your Javascript goes here
]]>
</script>
```

I hoe this helps